# Select from table where value exists?

Tags: postgresql, select, join

If a value, `value_two` does not exist (or `null`) in `table_two` I want to default to the value, `value_two` in `table_one`.

I have the following query format:

```
SELECT one.value_one, two.value_two
    FROM schema.table_one one 
    LEFT JOIN schema.table_two two 
        ON one.id_value = two.id_value and two.other_column = 'other_val'
    WHERE one.id_value = 'id_val';
```

I know one option is to select *all* of the values and handle it on the client side after returning the following:

```
SELECT one.value_one, one.value_two, two.value_two as two_value_two
    FROM schema.table_one one 
    LEFT JOIN schema.table_two two 
        ON one.id_value = two.id_value and two.other_column = 'other_val'
    WHERE one.id_value = 'id_val';
```

**Is there a 'clean' way check if `two.value_two` exists and default to select `one.value_two` if it doesn't?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`COALESCE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql) function.

`COALESCE` returns the first of its arguments that is non null.

Use it like this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(two.value_two, one.value_two)
FROM schema.table_one one 
LEFT JOIN schema.table_two two ON one.id_value = two.id_value and two.other_column = 'other_val' 
WHERE one.id_value = 'id_val';
```

Note that `COALESCE` is an ANSI SQL function and as such is available in all implementations of SQL (MySQL, MS SQL Server, ...)

Answer (score 1):

```
select one.value_one, coalesce(two.value_two, one.value_two)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL